# Difference between HERE Playground and REST Connector results

Tags: here-api

I'm using HERE API to find places for my project near a specific location, and while I was playing with the tool they provide in the [Documentation page](https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/276jx7ps-b9db5d9dd7ca028da524f98c06012a20;context=Zmxvdy1pZD05MGFhZjE2Mi01ODAzLTUyZGMtYjgwZC1iYWVlN2EzYjMwNmFfMTU5MDA4OTU4Mzc2MV8wXzE4NTYmc2l6ZT01JlgtRldELUFQUC1JRD1EZW1vQXBwSWQwMTA4MjAxM0dBTCZYLU5MUC1UZXN0aW5nPTE?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg), I found that the result gave me TripAdvisor description, which it was great, but when I call the REST service from my code, TripAdvisor result is never returned. For example:

Place ID to test the difference: 276jx7ps-b9db5d9dd7ca028da524f98c06012a20

From [HERE page](https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/276jx7ps-b9db5d9dd7ca028da524f98c06012a20;context=Zmxvdy1pZD05MGFhZjE2Mi01ODAzLTUyZGMtYjgwZC1iYWVlN2EzYjMwNmFfMTU5MDA4OTU4Mzc2MV8wXzE4NTYmc2l6ZT01JlgtRldELUFQUC1JRD1EZW1vQXBwSWQwMTA4MjAxM0dBTCZYLU5MUC1UZXN0aW5nPTE?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg):

[HERE Json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iG8L.png)

My code (in Go):

r, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/lookup?source=sharing&id=%s&apikey=%s", id, myAPIKey))

```
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer r.Body.Close()

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Println(string(body))
```

[Json received from my REST connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMxSA.png)

I'm using lookup service that makes a redirect to the one that I mentioned from HERE at the first place. I also tested it with the same URI that I passed from HERE example (just to see if the error was caused by the redirection) but I received the same response.

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: Welcome on S.O. Can you edit the question and add the request from your REST connector as it is sent (and after removing your API key) ?

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I just edit it and put the code example I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is actually expected that Freemium API credentials do not integrate reviews from external APIs, such as Tripadvisor or Facebook.
Although a bit cryptic, see the information regarding "external references" on [this page](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/external-references.html).

It is surely confusing, because the demo app credentials are provisioned with more features, and as a consequence do not provide a one-to-one experience with a developer on the Freemium plan. To make things more confusing, the set of active or inactive features is not something that is clearly shown in the Developer Portal.

Anyway, there is a method for you to get Tripadvisor reviews. You need to add a parameter to the HERE request, so that you receive the Tripadvisor id of the POI. Then, you can query the Tripadvisor API, assuming you preliminary get Tripadvisor API credentials.

This is done by adding `show_refs=tripadvisor` to the HERE query url:

**Example**

```sh
https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/lookup?show_refs=tripadvisor&id=276jx7ps-b9db5d9dd7ca028da524f98c06012a20&source=sharing&apiKey=<YOUR-API-KEY>
```

Then, if available, you get the following additional object in response:

```js
"references": {
    "tripadvisor": {
        "id": "6896648"
    }
}
```

From there you query the Tripadvisor API with the above identifier, to get reviews.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I have already tried it with show_refs, but the problem is that TripAdvisor denied me an api key for my project, so I can't call their API.
It might be because of having a Freemium plan, as you said, that's why I only get information from wikipedia in "editorials" and not from TripAdvisor. I couldn't find that information in the HERE documentation.